# Consumer Choice

Tags: microeconomics

Which of the following statements are not consistent with the assumption of completeness and transitivity? Explain why.
a) I just can't decide whether I would rather take a holiday in Spain or purchase a pair of skis.
b) After I've played two games of tennis, I don't want to play anymore.
c) If you give me a ticket to the football match, I'll five you my new pair of socks.

Comment: Welcome to the Economics StackExchange. Our policy is that when people ask for homework help (or just help in general) that they have to show that they put effort into it and specify what they are having trouble with. Do you not understand what completeness or transitivity is? At any rate this seems like a very simply question that could be solved by Googling those terms. This ain't Yahoo answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** *Completeness* states that for every item under consideration, you have some sort of preference over them, which can include indifference. You must be decided on how you feel between the items though. *Transitivity* means if you prefer item A to B and you prefer B to C, then you must prefer A to C.

That should be enough information to answer the question.